# Forcibly format column as Date in sheets onOpen() with Javascript

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple sheet that gets some date data submitted via a form. The form works great, data is collected, but I have to click on the column, and do *Format* → *Number* → **Date** in order to get dates to sort properly when used in the subsequent pivot table reports.

I don't know why dates aren't being treated as dates when the form submits it, but I don't care, my thought was just to have a trigger as to when the sheet opens, the column gets formatted so the user doesn't have to do it by hand.

I've done the tutorials for adding the `onOpen()` event to customise a menu, and called some other Javascript, but don't I have a clue as to what the necessary Javascript is to format the column—in this case, Column C. If somebody can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The method [setNumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) does the job:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C:C");
  range.setNumberFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

This formats column C as yyyy/MM/dd. Many other date formats are available: the method `setNumberFormat` supports Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).